# Programmatically add Click EventHandler to Button

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseclick-event

I'm creating Buttons programmatically with a method and am wanting to attach a Click event handler. However, that data currently comes from a string parameter which can't be used with `+= RoutedEventHandler`.

```cs
public Button CreateButton(string Display, string Name, string ClickEventHandler)
{
    Button Btn = new Button
    {
        Content = Display,
        Name = "Btn_" + Name
    };
    Btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(ClickEventHandler);

    return Btn;
}

void Btn_save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

// later
Button MyButton = CreateButton("Save", "save", "Btn_save_Click");
```

Error is `RoutedEventHandler` expects a `Method` and not a `String`. Is there a different approach to programmatically binding events that allows this sort of behaviour?
Thanks

Comment: a. Pass the method without quotes. b. In WPF don't use events, use command bindings.

Comment: this is fundamentally wrong. should read the tutorial again https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-add-an-event-handler-using-code

Comment: @DannyVarod a bit too strict to say WPF doesnt use events. if the event is at view level then its perfectly fine.

Comment: @Steve I think what Danny meant was *you shouldn't use events*, instead you should use command bindings. He never said, "WPF doesn't use events"...

Comment: @Steve, as Codexer said, I never said that. Just because you can do something, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Moreso, don't programmatically create buttons in WPF - you should bind a list of buttons to a list of commands in your view-model. Please do yourself a favor and read about mvvm in WPF, data-binding, command-binding etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand you wish to pass the method that should be executed when `Click` event is triggered. You could do something along the lines of:

```
Button button = CreateButton("Save", "save", (s, e) => SomeOnClickEvent(s, e));
Button button2 = CreateButton("Create", "create", (s, e) => SomeOtherOnClickEvent(s, e));

public Button CreateButton(string display, string name, Action<object, EventArgs> click)
{
    Button b = new Button()
    {
        Content = display,
        Name = $"Btn_{name}"
    };

    b.Click += new EventHandler(click);

    return b;
}

void SomeOnClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

void SomeOtherOnClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Just because this will work, doesn't mean this is a good practice.

Comment: @DannyVarod I agree, though why do you think that would be considered bad practice?

Comment: See latest comment to question, the correct way to do this is using bindings and command bindings, i.e. binding a list of buttons to a list of VM objects.

Answer (score 6):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish with this.

Here is an example of how to create an event at run time.

```
public void CreateButton()
{
  Button Btn = new Button();

  Btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Clicked);


}

private void btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // Your Logic here
}
```

Comment: Just because this will work, doesn't mean this is a good practice.

Comment: @DannyVarod So you just write that comment everywhere? I could see an argument about my answer, but this one is just the standard way to declare an event.

Comment: The answer is correct, I just wouldn't want to see people doing this. I recommend you show a better alternative. Some people actually learn from this site, so best to provide good practices and not just answer any question to get points.

Comment: Late maybe... but indulge me @DannyVarod because I have an aeronautical science degree. I’ve done my best to learn the world I am in which involves a lot of hours on this site. If this isn’t up to current standards for someone getting into this industry then what do you recommend?

Comment: @ReeseJones I recommend you read a bit about MVVM including data binding and command binding in WPF. It is a much cleaner way of doing things which has been around since the first version of WPF links https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2013/03/13/understanding-the-basics-of-mvvm-design-pattern/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview

Comment: @DannyVarod I have actually been learning and working with mvvm on a WPF application and have been doing a lot of control binding. For this post I was only giving an answer for the best way I knew and didn’t assume they were using WPF. I appreciate the feedback and link I will be using it going forward.

Comment: Glad to hear, next time note the tags on the question.